# Calculate transform scale based on div width and height

Tags: reactjs

As per the css the page_layout  is overflow and hidden.

I want to scale the page_layout  to fit inside the wrapper div.

I want to calculate the transform scale values and adjust the page layout

page_layout is zoomable initially it will the scaled to wrapper div on using slide the scale will change

I have set the page_layout width x height to width x height = 595 x 842 pt i.e 793px  x 1112px

I want to have a div width based on pdf A4 width and height.

so that I can export the html to div.

I have two questions
1)How to calculate the transform scale value
2)is the page_layout width and height is correct

```
const pageRef = React.useRef();
const wrapperRef= React.useRef();

calculateTransformScale =(e) => function () {
 var pageDom =pageRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
 var wrapperDom =wrapperRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
}
return (
<div class="wrapper" ref={wrapperRef}>
     <div class="page_layout" ref={pageRef}>
     </div>
</div>
);
```

```
css
.wrapper {
    height: calc(100% - 85px);
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    max-width: none;
    width: calc(100%);
    overflow: scroll;
}
.page_layout {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 793px;
    position: relative;
    height: 1122px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I have added  sandbox link
to scale the div on slider.
But one issue
Initially the div should fit inside the wrapper and on scale it should resize.

Sandbox Link
[enter link description here](https://v2ko3.csb.app/src/App.js)

[image]